# Up-arrow history matching in powershell 7

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7.0

I'd like to get history matching in powershell 7 like: when I type `npm`  and <kbd>up</kbd> arrow key, it would show my last command started with the keyword `npm` (Ex: `npm run build`).

I was able to achieve this in powershell 5 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1199882/powershell-auto-complete-settings). But this is not working in 7. When I run the discussed command:

```bsh
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
```

I'm getting an error like:

```
Update-Module: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Key'.
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7) the parameter is called `Chord`. Use `-Chord UpArrow` in place of `-Key UpArrow`.